# How to fetch seamarks with Overpass API?

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api, xapi, openseamap

I have currently managed to fetch `seamarks:type=harbours` with XAPI but I found out that XAPI is outdated now and it is better to use Overpass API.

My problem is I have no idea how to convert my search from XAPI to Overpass API.

This is my XAPI search:

```
http://www.overpass-api.de/api/xapi?node[seamark%3Atype=harbour][bbox=4.04297,51.63984,5.09216,51.87106]
```

This is the Overpass API request I have tried and it does not work. Nothing is received back. No exceptions are shown:

```
   [out:json][timeout:25];
(
  node["seamark:type=harbour"](4.04297,51.63984,5.09216,51.87106);
 
);

out body;
>;
out skel qt;
```

Could you help me out with what is my issue here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your bounding box is wrong. XAPI uses minlon,minlat,maxlon,maxlat while Overpass API uses minlat,minlon,maxlat,maxlon.

Try this query instead: https://overpass-turbo.eu/s/14R8

```
[out:json][timeout:25];
(
  node["seamark:type=harbour"](4.04297,51.63984,5.09216,51.87106);
);

out body;
>;
out skel qt;
```